# What is the probability of 1st January being the birthday of two persons among 500?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations, solution-verification, birthday

$\mathbf{Question:}$ What is the probability of $1$st January being the birthday of $two$ people when chosen (two persons are picked randomly) among $500$ people? ($365$ days in a Year).

$\mathbf{Attempt:}$ Let us denote the persons by $p_i$, $1\leq i \leq 500$. We write the birthdays as the "$n$ th" day of the year. The set of all possibilities:

$S=\{\{p_1,1\},\{p_1,2\},...,\{p_1,365\},\{p_2,1\},\{p_2,2\},...,\{p_2,365\},...,\{p_{500},1\},\{p_{500},2\},...,\{p_{500},365\} \}$.

$|S|=500 \times 365=182500$. Denote $\{p_i,j\}\equiv x_{i,j}$, $1\leq j\leq 365$.

Now, when we pick two persons at random, the total number of possibilites become : $\displaystyle{{182500}\choose{2}} -500 \times {365 \choose 2}=N$ (say). 
[Explanation: When we pick $u=\{p_1,1\}$, we cannot choose another possible value of $p_1$. So the other choice is from the rest of the elements of $S$, which amounts to $182500-365=182135$ possible pairs involving $u$. Continuing, we get $182500*182135/2=N$].

Now, the number of possible outcomes when picked two at a time from the set $\{\{p_1,1\},\{p_2,1\},...,\{p_{500},1\}\}$ is ${500 \choose 2}=P$ (say).

Therefore, the answer is $P/N=\displaystyle \frac{1}{133225}$.

Is this okay? Kindly verify.

Comment: No.  This should be a very straightforward application of a binomial distribution (*once certain simplifications and assumptions are made explicit*).  For starters, your "*set of all possibilities*" is way off since each individual *possibility* here should have been able to fully describe *all* people present.

Comment: Your answer is equal to 1/365 * 1/365, which is the probability that two specific, random people were both born on January 1 (equal to the chance the first was born on Jan 1 times the chance the second was born on Jan 1). But we have 500 people, not 2, so the chance should be quite a bit higher than that. Also, the question needs to be clarified - are you looking for the probability that *exactly* 2 of 500 people are born on Jan 1, or the probability that *at least* 2 people of 500 are born on Jan 1?

Comment: The probability that exactly two people out of 500 whose birthdays were independently selected from a uniform distribution over the $365$ possible birthdays in a year not including February 29 (*leap day*) happened to be Jan1 is $\binom{500}{2}\cdot \frac{364^{498}}{365^{500}}$.  @NuclearWang's answer of $\frac{1}{365}\cdot \frac{1}{365}$ is the probability that *very specifically* the first person and the second person were both born Jan1 and that the remaining $498$ people don't matter.

Comment: You should clarify the question: are you asking about two people randomly chosen out of 500 or about the existence of two such people among given 500.